# Checking to see if a string is already added into a list c#

Tags: c#

I am working on some c# I have inherited.

I have a problem in that something is being repeated twice in the output, I think I have identified in the controller where this is being added;

```
if(!isDirectUK)
  rollingPriceSupp.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, float>("Personal Insurance",
                                                       (float)insuranceCost));
ViewData["vRollingPrice"] = rollingPriceSupp;
```

How can I put a check at that point to see if the string "Personal Insurance" has already been added, so as to avoid it bieng repeated twice ?

Comment: Hey ivor - I've edited the code to what I assume you meant - feel free to change it if it's not (use the "edit" link just below your question). Use the 1010 button on the editor to indent code (or just type 4 spaces manually).

Comment: thanks for the tips Dominic, i will use them in futre.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add an

```
if(rollingPriceSupp.ContainsKey("Personal Insurance"))
```

check prior to the Add method.

UPDATE: Since seeing the OPs comment, the List is implemented using a `List<KeyValuePair>` colletion. In this case the ContainsKey alone would not work.

From the question alone I figured that they use some kind of Hashtable collection. In this case the containsKey would be sufficient.
If you cannot change the implementation from List to a Hashtable, then the solution would be to iterate through the items and check if it contains the key. E.g.

```
bool bItemExists = false;
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, float> pItem in rollingPriceSupp)
{
   if(pItem.Key == "Personal Insurance")
   {
      bItemExists = true;
      break;
   }
}
if(!bItemExists)
{
    rollingPriceSupp.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, float>("Personal Insurance",
                                                       (float)insuranceCost));
}
```

That should do the trick for you. Not the most efficient solution perhaps but should work.

Comment: ContainsKey is a method, so you have to use normal brackets instead of "straight" brackets.

Comment: Changed it
BTW, they're called parentheses, not normal brackets

Comment: Cheers, I tried this;

if (!isDirectUK)
            {
              if (rollingPriceSupp.ContainsKey("Personal Insurance"))
                rollingPriceSupp.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, float>("Personal Insurance", (float)insuranceCost));
            }

but I'm getting a warning that the systems.collections.generic .list does not contain a definaition for contains key, am i implemnting this wrong ?

Comment: it seems this is where the rollingprice is set up, it mentions list

public List<KeyValuePair<string, float>> rollingPriceSupp = new List<KeyValuePair<string, float>>();

Should the containskey method work here ?

Comment: @Nikos (OT): _parentheses_ would be American English, _brackets_ are commonly used in British English.

Comment: @RedGlyph (even more OT): Parentheses would be greek... I would know!

Comment: @ivor: The problem is that it is implemented with a List<KeyValuePair>. Perhaps it would be better of using a Hashtable collection type.

Comment: This code checks if the string exists in the collection then adds another copy if it does. Should it be: if(!bItemExists) ? Or am I not understanding the question?

Answer (score 2):

The IEnumerable extension methods offer several possibilities, including Count:

```
var count = rollingPriceSupp.Count(x => x.Key.Equals("Personal Insurance"));
var containsMultiple = count > 1;
```

The Where or FirstOrDefault methods might be good options also.

Answer (score 1):

If, as Nikos Steiakakis says, you are using a `List<KeyValuePair<string, float>>`, then my question to you is: **why?** *Particularly* if you don't want duplicate keys, you should *definitely* be using a `Dictionary<string, float>`, a nice little side-benefit of which would be that you don't have to write:

```
rollingPriceSupp.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, float>("Personal Insurance",
                                                     (float)insuranceCost));
```

Rather, you can simply write:

```
rollingPriceSupp.Add("Personal Insurance", (float)insuranceCost));
```

If random access by index is necessary, then I suppose you may indeed need to use a `List`. In that case you can use the `FindIndex` method (no need for extensions):

```
// this function will give you a Predicate to check for any key
public Predicate<KeyValuePair<string, float>> GetMatcher(string key) {
    return (KeyValuePair<string, float> item) => { return item.Key == key; };
}

int index = rollingPriceSupp.FindIndex(GetMatcher("Personal Insurance"));
bool keyExists = (index != -1);

if (!keyExists && !isDirectUK) {
    rollingPriceSupp.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, float>("Personal Insurance",
                                                         (float)insuranceCost));
}
```

Be aware, however, that this approach (a brute-force search for a duplicate key) is going to require iterating and will therefore have O(n) performance, which may or may not be acceptable depending on the size of your `List`. If performance is a priority and you can afford to allocate some extra memory, you might want to consider maintaining a `HashSet<string>` side-by-side with your list, so that when you add you do this:

```
HashSet<string> rollingPriceSuppKeys = new HashSet<string>();

if (!rollingPriceSuppKeys.Contains("Personal Insurance") && !isDirectUK) {
    rollingPriceSupp.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, float>("Personal Insurance",
                                                         (float)insuranceCost));
    rollingPriceSuppKeys.Add("Personal Insurance");
}
```

Comment: @Dan: Really detailed answer! +1. In my post I mention the possibility that he might not be able to change the implementation of List<KeyValuePair> since I have occured such situations in the past. It could be part of an older implementation that he does not have access to...

Comment: Im a bit reluctant to change the existing code i have inherited - particularly as I am quite new to c#. Im approaching the problem with trying to work with a temporary fix until I understand the whole thing much clearer.

Comment: @Nikos: Understood, and you were right to acknowledge that possibility. Essentially you and I have suggested the same thing in that case: a brute-force search (though I prefer using `FindIndex`, which already exists). But I actually feel that the best option of all would be to use a `HashSet`, or even to write a wrapper class that holds a `List` *and* a `HashSet`, so that there's no need to iterate through the list one by one to find a duplicate key.

Comment: Thanks for everyones help - everything is sorted now.

Answer (score -1):

Use the ContainsKey(key) instance method on your dictionary object.

Comment: Errr. Why is this being downvoted? Because it's not a complete book novel?

Comment: See Nikos Steiakakis's answer. The OP is maintaining legacy code that deals with a `List<KeyValuePair<string, float>>`, *not* an `IDictionary<string, float>`; so `ContainsKey` is not an option. (I'm not the one who downvoted you, though.)